# Estimate length of a curve, using left sum

Tags: integration

I'm asked to estimate the length of a curve $x^2$ in the interval $[0, 2]$ with $n = 5$. The guy wants me to use the formula $L = \int {\sqrt {(1 + f'(x)^2)}} \,dx$, to calculate a "left sum" of the graph in $[0, 2]$ with $5$ sub intervals.
  
So I'm really confused by that, because I thought the left sum can only be used to find area. 
I emailed him and he guaranteed it is possible.
  His answer is $4.0480127986983730101003658887008$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**
Your integral is

$$\int_0^2\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx$$

Now use left Riemann sums to estimate it.

**ADDENDUM**: When you calculate an integral your technically calculating the "area" underneath the function. But the integral $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$ is the length of the curve $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b].$ Next time look at the context of the question instead of using falsely preconceived intuitive notions.

Comment: You da beast! Thanks!